# Iniciante em samba4, controlador de domínio

Tags: linux, samba

Já visitei diversos sites em busca de exemplos de como fazer o samba4 rodar o serviço de controlador de domínio, o problema que seguem nestes tutorias é que acabo recebendo algum tipo de erro em alguma etapa e não tenho um retorno de ajuda.

**Problema:** Após fazer a instalação/configuração do *samba4* executei o comando para fazer o teste e falhou conforme abaixo:

```
root@serverLdap:/usr/local/samba/bin# /usr/local/samba/bin/smbclient -L localhost -U Administrator
Enter Administrator's password:
tdb(/usr/local/samba/var/lock/gencache_notrans.tdb): tdb_open_ex: spinlocks no longer supported
tdb(/usr/local/samba/var/lock/gencache_notrans.tdb): tdb_open_ex: spinlocks no longer supported
tdb(/usr/local/samba/var/lock/gencache_notrans.tdb): tdb_open_ex: spinlocks no longer supported
session setup failed: NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Comment: Qual versão de linux você está utilizando?

Comment: tentei com o debian, depois com o ubuntu, esses que eu tenho mais facilidade

Comment: Conseguiu resolver seu problema?

Comment: "Resolver" o problema não consegui não, mas desviei o problema fazendo uma instalação seguindo esses passos do zero https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rf7Hk8qWt1Q